# Como compilar a biblioteca JSON-C no Windows?

Tags: json

Pessoal baixei o código fonte da lib json-c, mas não sei como compilar usando o codeblocks

Comment: Tu já tentou adicionar ela às flags nas configurações do codeblocks?